Is "clap somebody out" common or is it used to encourage someone to get on stage for performance?
I have watched the film "Christmas with you".
In the film, the woman invited a man to get on stage to play the piano but he refused and then she cried "clap him out, everyone".
Most dictionaries don't have "clap somebody out" except Cambridge.

clap someone out phrasal verb with clap verb uk  /klæp/ us  /klæp/
-pp- Add to word list  to stand and clap as someone leaves a place, especially someone who is leaving for the last time because they have
graduated, are retiring, etc.

And Cambridge does not have examples about "clap somebody out".
When we encourage a person to get on stage, should we say "clap him out, everyone"? or "give him a big hand, everyone"?
Do British people even use "clap somebody out"? If not, what other phrase is used in the UK?

"Let's give {person} a big hand" is typically said by an MC as they introduce a person to the audience and  that person is about to come out on stage. The phrase isn't used to cajole a reluctant person to come out on stage.

@TimR - I'm reminded of the 'Dame Edna Everage' character of Barry Humphries, who told a chat-show interviewer that she liked a 'big hand on my entrance'.

@Michael Harvey:  'I told the doctors, "I'm not getting off this bed until I've had the thumbs up from each one of you."'

I don't think that "clapping somebody to encourage them to go on stage" is a sufficiently common experience that there is a set phrase for it.
I would take it that woman calling that (or, of course, the scriptwriter) made up the phrase on the spur of the moment, confident that in context people would understand what was meant.
